# Select elements with id attribute that starts/ends with a particular value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

Can jQuery or JavaScript be used with a regex to select multiple elements with similar id?

I have the following paragraphs:

```
<p id="item5_2"> A </p>
<p id="item9_5"> B </p>
<p id="item14_2"> C </p>
```

I want to change the content of paragraphs with id starting in `item` and ending in `2`.

I used the following jQuery:

```
$("#item[\d]*2").html("D");
```

but it doesn't work. How can I get it to work?

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/alexix/d5nHL/1/)

Comment: with similar ids?? ids should be unique.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar similar != same

Comment: Am I the only one who noticed that all answers so far check if the ID ends with `2`, but there is one ending with `5`?

Comment: @nyuszika7h read the question again :) (nem jut eszembe idevágó nyuszikás vicc)

Comment: @marczellm Oh, sorry, I see. I guess I shouldn't be on SO this late. :P

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes it can, you can combine the [attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and the [attribute ends with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selector

```
$('[id^="item"][id$="2"]').html("D");
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/d5nHL/2/) *(and you have to enable jQuery in the fiddle)*

you can't use regex to match the numbers in between though, for that you'd need [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$('[id^="item"]').filter(function() {
    return this.id.match(/item\d+_2/);
}).html("D");
```

Comment: This is a good answer for the question, but I'd like to address the elephant in the room.  __selecting based on a partial id match__ is a __horrible__ approach that completely disregards [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Especially when you can use arrays instead to obtain the same result. Don't put business logic in the presentation layer of your application. Doing these sort of selections is a common mistake in developers that are taking their first steps in coding UI and it is best avoided.

Answer (score 15):

You can use "*start with*" and "*ends with*" selectors provided by jQuery, like below.

```
$("[id^='item'][id$='2']").html("D");
```

Official documentation:

- [Start with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)
- [Ends with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

Answer (score 9):

The best way to go is to use **[the following jQuery selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors)**

```
^= is starts with
$= is ends with

=  is exactly equal
!= is not equal
*= is contains
```

So in your  case:

```
var $items = $('[id^="item"][id$="2"]');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can combine attribute selectors: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M7Luv/)

```
$("[id^='item'][id$='2']").html("D");
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
 <p id="item5_2"> A </p>
 <p id="item9_5"> B </p>
 <p id="item14_2"> C </p>
```

and...

```
 $('[id^="item"][id$="2"]')
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the working [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/M8Sx6/1/)

HTML:

```
<p id="item5_2"> A </p>
<p id="item9_5"> B </p>
<p id="item14_2"> C </p>
<input type="button" value="Get element ids starting with 'item' and ending with '2'" onclick="get_ids()">
```

JS:

```
get_ids = function(){
    $('[id^="item"][id$="2"]').each(function() {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use next code if you want to do any other action:

```
$('[id^="item"]').each(function(){
  if(this.id.slice(-1) == 2){
    //Do something
    $(this).html('D');
  }

});
```