# Jquery: Getting the values of different radio buttons groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two radio button groups. The problem here is, the result returned by the val() is not consistent, and it seems the output is stuck with some old value. What am I missing?

```
<form id="form_1">
    <div id="myForm_1">

        <input type="radio" name="radioName_1" value="1" /> 1 <br />
        <input type="radio" name="radioName_1" value="2" /> 2 <br />
        <input type="radio" name="radioName_1" value="3" /> 3 <br />
    </div>
</form>
<hr>
<form id="form_2">
    <div id="myForm_2">
        <div id="new">
            <input type="radio" name="radioName_2" value="4" /> 4 <br />
            <input type="radio" name="radioName_2" value="5" /> 5 <br />
            <input type="radio" name="radioName_2" value="6" /> 6 <br />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the javascript is:

```
$('input').on('change', function() {
   var question = $(this).closest("form").attr("id");
   var selected = $('input[name^=radioName]:checked').val();
   var msg = question + " " + selected;
   alert(msg); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RhnvU/1847/

Comment: It is because, you have two sets

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/22KnB/1/

Comment: `^= is starts with` http://stackoverflow.com/a/24082176/3300831

Comment: @shaunakde Pardon please. Shouldn't the jquery 'on change' event refreshed the value of val() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CwBkg/)

Use `$(this).val()` or `this.value` to keep it simple - You need current selected value, but as you have two sets of radio buttons, it was getting the selected value from the first set.

```
$('input').on('change', function() {
   var question = $(this).closest("form").prop("id");
   var selected = $(this).val();   //or this.value
   var msg = question + " " + selected;
   alert(msg); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ew3ZU/18/)**

`this.value` used for select current radio button value  in javascript and  `closest()` used for select parent

```
  $('input').on('change', function () {
    var question = $(this).closest("form").prop("id");
    var selected = this.value;
    var msg = question + " " + selected;
    alert(msg);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('input').on('change', function() {
 var question = $(this).closest("form").attr("id");
  var selected = $(this).val();
  var msg = question + " " + selected;
  alert(msg); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this : Actually you are looking for the same radio button for which change event fired.
So need to check value of current radio button only.

```
$('input').on('change', function() {
   var question = $(this).closest("form").attr("id");
   var selected =  $(this).val();
   var msg = question + " " + selected;
   alert(msg); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should find the selected input in current form using:

```
$('input').on('change', function() {
 var question = $(this).closest("form").attr("id");
 var selected = $(this).val();
 var msg = question + " " + selected;
 alert(msg); 
});
```

Comment: Clicked radio will have the checked property. right? then is it necessary to search it in the whole form?